# slicing a big 2d array into smaller 2d array with no contiguous columns

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I have an array of shape (720,48). How to slice a smaller array containing all the rows with the 24 first columns along with the last 7 columns.

Comment: (720,48) dimensions to which dimensions?

Comment: Is that a numpy array ? if yes simply use basic indexing: `[:24,-7:]`

Comment: x_train is my (720,48) numpy array, when I try to slice x_part I got an error message:             x_part=x_train[: , [:24,-7:]]
  File "C:\Users\HDPC\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6992/4048703398.py", line 1
    x_part=x_train[:,[:24,-7:]]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax